# Creating a desginer in WebApplication

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am planning to develop a small web application, which enable users to create small application according to their needs. The layout of the web page should be like visual-studio, where:

- The left pane contains all the controls (I only provide few basic controls like txt box, lbl etc)
- The right pane contains the properties of currently selected control (again only few basic properties like color, font etc)
- And the canvas lies in the middle of page, where user drag and drop controls and set their properties

I am beginner, please guide me where to start and what resources to study. According to my knowledge I need to do some scripting (JavaScript, jQuery, GWT). If that's right then what scripting languages should I use with ASP.net and C#

## Edit:

I have experience of web application development but I never used scripting, **so I only need guidance regarding scripting**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an absolute beginner I would recommend by doing some reading on W3Schools.
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp

If you're looking for a good book, I would recommend - Beginning ASP.NET 3.5: In C# and VB (Programmer to Programmer) by Imar Spaanjaars. I've used the book to teach myself the basics of .NET and it is quite good.

I don't know much about scripting, but I would suggest that you try/start building the website in Visual Studio and learn the scripting languages as the need arises.